# Current source for high current LED driver- 24Vdc/max:16A

Tags: operational-amplifier, current, mosfet-driver, led-driver, source

I am working on designing a current source for a LED driver, which can work up to max:16A, as long as stays On less than 500msec.
Actually, the leds circutry is a Dome-light which is divided in 4 sectors. The 4 sectors have a common ground and they are trigger in PNP mode(24Vdc) individually.

[image: DOME light, 4 sectors]

I am using a current sense-resistor of 10mOhm resistance, between a n-channel mosfet`s source terminal and ground. The voltage measured on the current sense-resistor is feed to a differencial OpAmp which output controls the mosfet´s gate voltage. Nothing new here, it is the simplest current source circuit.
I am using a digital rheostat to create a voltage divider which sets the OpAmps reference voltage on the non-inverting terminal:
[image]
 Components:
 - TLV2372IP (Op Amp)
 - MCP4162 (Digital Rheostat)
 - STP55NF06L (Mosfet 60V,55A,Rds-On 18mOhm)
 - Current sense-resistor 10mOhm/0.1% tolerance.

Basic schematic:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6Ooi9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**Questions:**

- The circuit drives the current to the leds array with stability. The power supply is a Meanwell DR-120-24/5A. Why can I get 4,6,8 or 15 Amps currents?If the power supply is rated 5 Amps max? (I didn´t have a higher current rated power supply at hand).
- I found in internet that a N-Channel or P-Channel MOSFET High-Side Drive should be more stable and worth to try. But How? I don´t know how to go about it. Could you give me some ideas, please?

This circuit it is for using the Dome_light for a photometric stereo machine vision application. Actually, I am a machine vision programmer. I am not an electronics engineer, sorry for not giving more information.
Thanks in advanced

**EDIT:IMPORTANT!**

**I have said that the circuit drives current with stability. But I know that this low-side driver will be unstabled if there is noise in the power supply or noisy enviroment like in a factory.It works steady only by chance.**
 It is why I will need to change the circuit to work in high-side, I think... Also as you can see, in the real circuit I have used a voltage follower with a second opamp which gives the sense resistor voltage-drop to the differential opamp.